# Como imprimir resultados de un filtro fuera de Consola?

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Deseo hacer una aplicación Android usando solo javascript y HTML.Que funcione sin necesidad de internet.Es una especie diccionario que te busca las palabras por nombre o categoría. Logré aplicar bien el filter.El problema que tengo es que el resultado solo me lo da por consola y asi no me sirve para una aplicación android ( de teléfono).
Necesito que el resultado de ese filtrado salga impreso por un document.write o poder sacarlo del script y imprimirlo en HTML , etiqueta  por ejemplo.
La duda es: Los resultados de un script como imprimirlo en HTML ?
Como puedo imprimir con document.write los resultados de un filter ?
Alguien conoce el método para hacerlo ?.
Estoy aprendiendo ahora, agradeceria comprensión y ayuda..Gracias...

```
'''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA- 
Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    const palabras = [{
        nombre: "alex",
        categoria: "verbo",
        traducion: "yupi"
    }, {
        nombre: "yoyo",
        categoria: "sustantivo",
        traducion: "wao"
    }, {
        nombre: "alexis",
        categoria: "verbo",
        traducion: "yupi"
    }, {
        nombre: "yoyolo",
        categoria: "sustantivo",
        traducion: "wao"
    }, ]
    const resultado = 
 palabras.filter(palabra => 
 palabra.categoria == 
"sustantivo")
        
    console.log(resultado)
</script>
</body>

</html>'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías generar una etiqueta `<p>` vacía, con alguna clase o id único y en el script atribuirle el resultado.
Ej:

```
document.getElementById("tuElemento").innerText = resultado
```

Comment: Perdone usted pero no se usar ese método. Por favor podría ponerme un programa de ejemplo para aprender ?.

Comment: Es decir, lo ejecuto con esa modificación y debe salir  ...Gracias hermano. Probaré

Comment: Aca te mando un pequeño ejemplo de como podrias lograrlo con un buscador que te muestre todos los elementos que coincidan con el nombre buscado en el input. https://jsfiddle.net/j7csvad2/

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente use `element.insertAdjacentHTML().` Es más fácil de usar `.append()`, ya que puede insertar marcado HTML directamente en un elemento DOM existente sin tener que crear primero elementos DOM secundarios con `document.createElement()`. Tampoco es tan perjudicial para el contenido de la página ya existente como `.innerHTML+=` ...lo sería.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA- 
Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    const palabras = [{
        nombre: "alex",
        categoria: "verbo",
        traducion: "yupi"
    }, {
        nombre: "yoyo",
        categoria: "sustantivo",
        traducion: "wao"
    }, {
        nombre: "alexis",
        categoria: "verbo",
        traducion: "yupi"
    }, {
        nombre: "yoyolo",
        categoria: "sustantivo",
        traducion: "wao"
    }, ]
    const resultado = 
 palabras.filter(palabra => 
 palabra.categoria == 
"sustantivo")
        
    console.log(resultado)
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",JSON.stringify(resultado))
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` es solo la forma en que elegiste mostrar la información. Con Javascript puedes programar lo necesario para que se muestre como quieras.

Esta solo es una de las maneras en que podrías hacerlo:

```js
const palabras = [{
    nombre: "alex",
    categoria: "verbo",
    traducion: "yupi"
}, {
    nombre: "yoyo",
    categoria: "sustantivo",
    traducion: "wao"
}, {
    nombre: "alexis",
    categoria: "verbo",
    traducion: "yupi"
}, {
    nombre: "yoyolo",
    categoria: "sustantivo",
    traducion: "wao"
}, ]

const resultado = 
 palabras.filter(palabra => 
 palabra.categoria == 
"sustantivo")

// Recupera los elementos 
let plantilla = document.querySelector(".plantilla")
let contenedor = document.querySelector(".contenedor")

// Hacer una función es buena idea ya que mostrar palabras será
// una tarea repetitiva
function mostrarPalabra(palabra){
    // Clona la plantilla
    let ePalabra = plantilla.cloneNode(true)
    // Se le quita la clase plantilla al clon
    ePalabra.classList.remove("plantilla")

    // Se modifican los contenidos de cada
    // etiqueta en el clon 
    ePalabra.querySelector(".nombre").textContent = palabra.nombre
    ePalabra.querySelector(".categoria").textContent = palabra.categoria
    ePalabra.querySelector(".traduccion").textContent = palabra.traduccion

    // Finalmente se agrega el clon al contenedor
    contenedor.appendChild(ePalabra)
}

// Se llama la función mostrarPalabra con cada palabra
resultado.forEach(palabra => mostrarPalabra(palabra))
```

```css
.plantilla {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
   <!-- La clase plantilla mantiene el elemento oculto -->
   <div class="plantilla palabra">
      <p class="nombre">Nombre</p>
      <p class="categoria">Categoría</p>
      <p class="traduccion">Traducción</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver que son muchos pasos para mostrar solo algunas cosas. Es por eso que se suele utilizar algún framework ya que facilitan la creación de elementos dinámicos.